# Creating parameterized SQL queries in XML file

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml

I have been asked to fix an SQL injection issue reported by a static analysis tool. The SQL queries are stored in an XML file as shown below.

```
<Import>
  <Command>select USERNAME as ID,USERNAME,(case PASSWORD when 'GLOBAL' then 1 else 0 end) as ISGLOBAL,(case PASSWORD when 'EXTERNAL' then 1 else 0 end) as ISEXTERNAL from dba_users</Command>
  <Command attribute="ROLES">select granted_role as ROLES from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where grantee='&amp;USERNAME'</Command>
  <Command attribute="PRIVS">select privilege as PRIVS from DBA_SYS_PRIVS where grantee='&amp;USERNAME'</Command>
</Import>
```

I have to replace the placeholders `grantee='&amp;USERNAME'` and `grantee='&amp;USERNAME'` with Query Parameters, like `@paramName` in SQL Server. I am from C++ background and I am new to SQL and .net.

Any guidelines will help me.

Comment: `grantee='&amp;USERNAME'` not `grantee=&amp;USERNAME`?

Comment: Why not store the parameter name in the XML (e.g, grantee=@UserName) so the parameterized query text can be used directly in the application?  The app code can then add the needed parameter objects and values without a SQL injection risk.

Comment: @DanGuzman: I am not getting what the author of the code is doing by saying grantee='&amp;USERNAME'? Anyway it finally boil downs to grantee='&USERNAME' in the query. But what is he trying to do?

Comment: The value of `'&amp;USERNAME'` becomes `&USERNAME'` after the XML replaces the entity reference.  The code must likely then performing simple string replacement of this token so that the resultant query becomes `WHERE grantee = 'ActualUserName'`.  This injection vulnerability needs to be fixed in the application code using the method I mentioned (parameterized query).  You cannot fix the issue with just a config file change.